# Can Giuliani represent Trump in an impeachment trial?

Tags: united-states, impeachment, conflict-of-interest

[Link.](https://abcnews.go.com/US/giuliani-working-trumps-impeachment-defense-argue-voter-fraud/story?id=75302032)

> President Donald Trump's personal attorney Rudy Giuliani tells ABC News he's working as part of the president's defense team in his upcoming second impeachment trial -- and that he's prepared to argue that the president's claims of widespread voter fraud did not constitute incitement to violence because the widely-debunked claims are true.

Question: Can Giuliani even legally represent Trump in the impeachment process?  Giuliani was a major participant in the events leading up to the alleged insurrection.  Isn't he likely to be called as a witness?  Isn't there a conflict of interest here?

NB: This question is only about the legality of Giuliani representing Trump.  The insurrection and impeachment itself can be discussed in other threads.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Impeachment is a **political** process. All rules in it are made by Politics. **No Courts Involved.** I think this should be migrated to politics.SE

Comment: Please don't close it. I wouldn't object to migrating it.  But I think the legality of Rudy as representative is a valid  Law question anyway.

Comment: Migration to another stack is handled via the same queue as closing. However, any rules for impeachment are *made up by congress the moment it starts the trial*. During the last impeachment of Trump we had to close and migrate quite a few questions that wanted to look into the political process.

Comment: @Trish the process of impeachment is governed by the constitution, which is the supreme law of the United States.  This question is not off topic.